# 100 lottery tickets are distributed, only 2 of them have a prize.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

100 lottery tickets are distributed, only 2 of them have a
  prize. Rupert Murdoch buys n of these tickets (n of course is some
  number between 0 and 100). What is the probability that Murdoch wins
  both prizes?

So I feel like this one shouldn't be hard at all, but I'm struggling. I know that there is a 2% or p=.02 chance of winning one prize if you buy one ticket. For some reason i get lost as soon as you buy more tickets and want to know the chance of winning both prizes. any help would be nice. I considered using a probability distribution, but couldn't find one that I thought would work. Thanks

Comment: Look into the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

Comment: I looked at the hypergeometric distribution but was discouraged that it wasn't any of the other ones so I don't think i gave it a fair chance. Does that mean that it would be ${2\choose2}*{98 \choose n-2}/{100 \choose n}$

Answer (score 3):

P(win both prizes)$=\frac{number\;of\;ways\;choosing\;n\;tickets\;containing\;both\;tickets }{number\;of\;ways\;choosing\;n\;tickets\;}$

There are $2\choose2$$100-2\choose n-2$ ways to choose the rest (n-2) tickets in order to win.

There are $100\choose n$ ways in total to choose n tickets.

So, P(win both prizes)=$\frac{{2 \choose 2}{100-2\choose n-2}}{100\choose n} $

Answer (score 0):

There are $n \choose 2$ ways to select the winning tickets from $n$ and ${100 \choose 2}$ overall ways to select the winning tickets, assuming the winners are interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $N$ is the total number of tickets, $k$ is the number of winning tickets, and $n$ is the number of tickets you buy. In your case $N=100, k=2, n\geq k$. As suggested in the comment above, the distribution of the random variable $X$= # of winning tickets after $n$ draws follows the hypergeometric distribution. Clearly the total number of ways you can buy $n$ tickets is ${N \choose n}$. The total number of good draws is ${k \choose k} \times {N-k \choose n-k}$. Hence, the probability is

$$\frac{{k \choose k} \times {N-k \choose n-k}} {N \choose n}=\frac{{98 \choose n-2}} {100 \choose n}.$$